# get user information from with sequilize in rest API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am creating a REST API with `nodejs` and `sequelize`  and I have 2 tables:

1. Users table
2. Friends table

With

```
/api/friends
```

I get all my friends list (stored in my Friends table) but I don't know how to get their name (from the User table).

This is my request to get my friends list:

```
models.Friend.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [{
      UserID: userFound.id
    },
    {
      idFriend: userFound.id
    }],
    status : "active"
  }
})
```

In the picture I show you the Users table and Friends table
[image: in the picture i show you the table user and friends]

How can I get the name of friend in my request ?

UPDATE 
this is my user model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    isAdmin: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    isOut: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    bio: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    models.User.hasMany(models.Message)
    models.User.hasMany(models.Friend)
  };
  return User;
};
```

and this is my friends models

```
    'use strict';
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      var Friend = sequelize.define('Friend', {
        UserID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        idFriend: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        status: DataTypes.STRING
      }, {});
      Friend.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        models.Message.belongsTo(models.User, {
          foreignKey:{
            allowNull: false
          }
        })
      };
      return Friend;
    };


and my get friends function

 showFriend: function (req, res) {
        var headerAuth = req.headers['authorization'];
        var UserId = jwtUtils.getUserId(headerAuth);

        // Params
        asyncLib.waterfall([
            function (done) {
                models.User.findOne({
                    where: { id: UserId }
                })
                    .then(function (userFound) {
                        done(null, userFound);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({ 'error': 'unable to verify user' });
                    });
            },
            function (userFound, TargetFound, done) {
                models.Friend.findAll({
                    where: {
                        $or: [{
                            UserID: userFound.id
                        },
                        {
                            idFriend: userFound.id
                        }],
                    status : "active"
                    }
                })
                    .then(function (friends) {
                        if (friends) {
                            res.status(200).json(friends);
                        } else {
                            res.status(404).json({ "error": "no friends found" });
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({ 'error': 'cannot find Friend' })
                    })
            }
        ], function (newFriend) {
            if (newFriend) {
                return res.status(201).json({
                    'newFriend': newFriend.id
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(500).json({ 'error': 'cannot add Friendss' })
            }
        });
    },
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If `Friend` and `Users` are associated, then you have to `include` them in your query:

```
models.Friend.findAll({
  where: {
    $or: [
      { UserID: userFound.id },
      { idFriend: userFound.id }
    ],
    status : "active"
  },
  include: [{
    model: models.User 
  }]
})
```

Then you should be able to do something like:

```
const friends = models.Friend.findAll({ ... })
friends.forEach((friend) => {
  /* depends on your Naming Strategy, I'm assuming 
   `Users` will load as property 'User' on `Friends`,
    it depends on how your models and associations are defined
  */
  console.log(friend.User.username)
})
```

Comment: i update my question with more detail using your advice i include my user model but when i do my showFriend call i got 'unable to verify user'